# Turn based multiplayer: making/verifying moves

Tags: android

I want to take my game to multiplayer using Skiller.  The multiplayer aspect occurs in a battle with the same style as Pokemon where monsters fight using player chosen moves.  Skiller uses a string that is sent between users to communicate the moves.  For a multiplayer game, should I:

(1) Send only the move name and have both players' clients calculate the result (damage).

(2) have the client making the move calculate the results and send it.

(3) send the move name and have both clients calculate the result and send them to check against each other

(4) a better option I don't know about

[Edit] At the beginning of the fight, a message would go back and forth so that both player's clients had all the info on the monsters (health, attack values, statuses) so that each could calculate the damage done based on the move.

If I would be verifying the result after a move is made, what should happen if they are getting different results?  It makes sense to verify but I'm not sure what I would want to do if it came back differently.

Comment: If you actually want to verify the moves, go with option 3. Checking against each other will make sure the game is in the same state on both clients. With option 1, if one is modded, they may see different results, but not know that.

Comment: Please put your response as an answer instead of comment so it can be rated/accepted.

Comment: It's not a hard and fast rule, so it doesn't feel like an *answer* to me. Honestly, I thought about voting to close as subjective, because there's no one answer to this issue, and many games do it in many ways.

Comment: @Geobits I'm still new to multiplayer dev so I wasn't sure how to best ask the question.  I would rather not make my game with the assumption that everything will work all the time, but I'm not sure how to respond when you get two different results from the players' clients.

Comment: I'd just give an explanatory dialog, and exit the battle/fight/game. The guilty side will know what it means. The innocent side may be confused, but they won't likely want to continue playing with a cheater, so probably won't be offended. YMMV, there are lots of options for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have the attacker send the move, then the defender(the guy who gets attacked) calculates the damage done.

To stay with the pokemon example, the reason why only the defender should calculate the damage is so the attacker does not need to receive a lot of information from the defender, for example Max health, a "defense" sort of attribute etc.
Then the defender sends the damage receive back to the attacker so both Players know what has happened.

I believe this is the best way to do it.